# Correction of figure in galley proofs in Elsevier journal

Tags: proofreading

I have submitted the final manuscript after it got accepted, but I just found one error in the figures. The mistake is copying overlap two figures (2 similar figures). This mistake did not occur in the first and second submissions for reviewing and answering revision. Hence, may I change this figures in galley proofs?

---

This is my mistake. This change does not affect the content of the paper. I have not yet received the online proofing version. Hence, should I wait to correct it in the galley proofs? or should I resend the correction version now?

Answer (score 1):

Is the error trivial (i.e. does not need to be peer reviewed, no reasonable person would object) or not? If it is trivial, then don't worry about it now and correct it during galley proofs. A sufficiently obvious error might even be spotted by the publisher when they do copyediting. If it is not trivial then let the editor know, since they might need to get the reviewer to check it again.

Comment: It is a trivial mistake, but it needs to correct. This figure has been reviewed, but before submitting the final version for galley proofs, I have some modifications about the size of symbols and then transferred it to the manuscripts. However, I have copied two figures with the same data (e.i, Figure 1a and Figure 1b). Is it possible to resend the correction version for galley proofs?

Comment: @DuongNguyen I don't understand what you mean I'm afraid. What is "I have copied two figures with the same data"? Do you mean you accidentally used the same data for two figures? If so this should be trivial and can be fixed during galley proofs.

Comment: it means that figure 1 including two figures a and b, but I have made a mistake when using figure 1b two times. The correction will be figure 1 a and b.

Comment: @DuongNguyen that's trivial alright, and you should be able to fix it during galley proofs without problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, Allure. I feel very terrible about this mistake.

Comment: @DuongNguyen don't feel bad. Publishers see these kind of mistakes all the time and you won't be inconvenience them at all. It's literally what they're paid to do. Relax, and work on your next paper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80362/discussion-between-duong-nguyen-and-allure).